# SQL запрос на GROUP BY

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, запрос

Есть 3 таблицы 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Требуется составить запрос:
Сведения о наличии деталей, цена которых > 100: detail.name; detail.price; общая стоимость (суммарно по всем складам).

Общая стоимость - это

```
число = detail.price * SUM(SELECT quantity FROM STOCK WHERE detail.id = STOCK.SETAIL_ID)
```

т.е. равно произведению цены детали на общее количество этих деталей на всех складах.

Как правильно построить запрос?

Спасибо

Comment: На каком этапе у вас возникла сложность? Приложите свои попытки

Answer (score 11, accepted):

как задача звучит так и пишите, только на sql.

выбрать, деталь, стоимость и суммарную стоимость

```
SELECT d.id, d.name, d.price, d.price*sum(s.quantity) as totalPrice
```

из деталей

```
FROM detail as d
```

которые есть на складах

```
INNER JOIN stock AS s ON (s.detail_id = d.id)
```

и у которых стоимость больше 100

```
WHERE d.price > 100
```

и группировочку по деталям

```
GROUP BY d.id, d.name, d.price
```

по суммарной стоимости в порядке убывания

```
ORDER BY totalPrice DESC
```

Comment: Рахмет
По полочкам

Comment: @KamilNHOT если подходит, то [отметьте ответ как правильный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)